# how to read serial port on windows 10 using php?

Tags: php, github, serial-port

I am trying to run this project but could not understand why i am seeing this error message when i run it.
This is the project https://github.com/oasynnoum/phpmake_serialport
I downloaded the zip file but when i use the sample code from http://sandbox.n-3.so/Gorilla/tutorial/#gorilla-serialport-tutorial-example i get error message as Class 'PHPMake\SerialPort' not found 
I added .dll file in php/ext folder of my xampp and also added extension in php.ini file
Also when i run basic-usage.php file i see Undefined variable: argc error message.
please can anyone look into it,it will be very helpful for me,Thank you in advance.

Comment: If use include 'SerialPort.php'; i think it solves one problem but now i am seeing" Call to a member function setVTime() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\serialphp\index.php" error message